# Adding filters to sheet with hundreds of header rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Good morning all,

I have a huge spreadsheet that I need to work with that has hundreds of different row headers. Essentially it is a file arranged by instructor name that shows the comments they have provided to students in their online courses. I need to see how many student submissions are receiving instructor feedback. I cannot for the life of me figure out how I can add filters properly (to limit the results to GRADED assignments for each instructor) so that I don't lose the row headers (the teacher names, which the report puts in a blue cell). When I add filters at the very top of the sheet, the individual row headers disappear. I have tried going to each row and adding filters that way, but it seems you can only have one active row filter at a time. Can any of you superstars figure out a way to manage this? My second issue is needing to calculate percentages of comments (versus none) for each instructor. I can't figure out a way to do this for each instructor without doing this manually.
[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nurZh.png)

Can anyone help? Thank you SO MUCH in advance!

Ms. Excel Scares Me

Comment: Here, I can't help. I have no idea of how your file is structured. The best way to be helped would be to create a small representative extract (3 instructors or something like this) of your data, what would like to see...)

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is in a "report" format that doesn't allow easy manipulation. You'll need complicated formulas or power query or Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) to convert the data. The other option is to get your data preformatted in a data "table" format, basically all rows and columns filled in. Then a pivot table would probably get you to your answer.

Comment: Your main problem is that your data rows omit much of the data that is necessary to understand the proper relationship between the columns.   Here is an example image with [properly entered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2fYz.png).  In order to manipulate your data, this will need to be generated manually or formulaicaly.  If it is possible, fix your data, if not, a formula will need to be created to key off the existing format to render the data sensical for the next steps

Comment: Thank you both for reading my question and responding. A system called Cognos generates the report...it does allow the option of downloading in HTML, CSV, XML, or Excel, but I don't know that any of those would help either. It's just a massive list of all the comments made by instructors in their courses and I have no idea how I can get a picture of what's going on without being able to summarize the data somehow. :-(

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Blind Spots. I see exactly what you mean. Unfortunately, a system generates this report. I will tinker a bit and see if reformatting it myself is at all possible. Otherwise, maybe the report can be rewritten to make the data more manageable. Thank you all!

Comment: Choose CSV and see what you get.   The issue isn't summarizing, the issue is currently associating the student with the assignment, with the course with the prof.

Comment: I included a formula in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1776784/) in case you can't figure out how to reformat.

Comment: OMG I will try this. Thank you so much, Blind Spots!!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1: Re-organize your data

The first hurdle is to reorganize your data.  Your data rows omit much of the data that is necessary to understand the proper relationship between the columns.

Here is an example image with properly entered data.
[image]

If it is possible, fix your data, if not, a formula needs to be created to key off the existing format to render the data sensical for the next steps.

###### Example Formula to Fix Data

```
=VSTACK(
    HSTACK( "Instructor", "Course", "Assignment", "Student", "Status", "Comments" ),
    TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,  BYROW(A2:A500, LAMBDA(x,
       LET(
          head, $A$1, _row, ROW(head), _col, COLUMN(head),
          student,  INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(x),_col+2)),
          rng, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(_row,_col)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(x),_col)),
          rngInstr, FILTER(rng, (LEN(rng)>0)*(LEN(OFFSET(rng, 1, 0))>0)),
          instructor, INDEX(rngInstr, COUNTA(rngInstr)),
          rngSubj, FILTER(rng, rng<>""), subject, INDEX(rngSubj, COUNTA(rngSubj<>"")),
          rngAsgn, FILTER(OFFSET(rng, 0, 1), OFFSET(rng, 0, 1)<>""),
          assignment, INDEX(rngAsgn, COUNTA(rngAsgn<>"")),
          status, IF(OFFSET(student,0,1)<>"",OFFSET(student,0,1),"-"),
          comment, IF(OFFSET(student,0,2)<>"",OFFSET(student,0,2),"-"),
          IF(student<>"", TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE, HSTACK(instructor, subject, assignment, student, status, comment)),"")
       )
    ))),",",";",FALSE)
 )
```

[image]

#### Step 2: Calculate % of Comments

1. Use UNIQUE to get the instructors list
   [image]
2. Divide the number of empty comments (`"-"`) for each instructor by the number of entries for each instructor
   [image]